# SeekBar Background Colour in other activities (Android)

Tags: android, xml, colors, background, seekbar

At the moment my code allows me to change the background of my main activity via a seekbar. How would I keep this change continued in all of my other activities.

E.g. When I move my seekbar the background changes to red in my main activity, however in my second activity the background is still white.

How do I go about updating it so that all of my activities match the colour of my main activity?

mainactivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{

        RelativeLayout myscreen; // SEEKBAR
        SeekBar rsb, gsb, bsb; // SEEKBAR
        int red, green, blue; //SEEKBAR

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            myscreen=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout); //SEEKBAR
            rsb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.RedSeekBar); //SEEKBAR
            gsb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.GreenSeekBar);//SEEKBAR
            bsb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.BlueSeekBar); //SEEKBAR
            rsb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); //SEEKBAR
            gsb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); //SEEKBAR
            bsb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); //SEEKBAR

            Button gotoscreen2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BgoToScreen2); //BUTTON
            gotoscreen2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   //BUTTON
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {   //BUTTON
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub   //BUTTON
                    Intent screen2 = new Intent("com.sunveersinghseera.seekbar.OURSECONDSCREEN");//BUTTON
                    startActivity(screen2);//BUTTON 
                    }
            });
        }

        public void updatebackground(){  //SEEKBAR
            red = rsb.getProgress();  //SEEKBAR
            green = gsb.getProgress();  //SEEKBAR
            blue = bsb.getProgress();  //SEEKBAR
            myscreen.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000+red*0x10000+green*0x100+blue); //SEEKBAR
        }

    Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            updatebackground();
}
```

secondpage.java

```
public class OurSecondScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    tools:context="com.sunveersinghseera.seekbar.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change the background" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BgoToScreen2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:text="Go To Screen 2" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/RedSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/GreenSeekBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:max="255"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/GreenSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:max="255"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RedSeekBar" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/BlueSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/GreenSeekBar"
        android:max="255"
        android:layout_below="@+id/GreenSeekBar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

secondpage.xml

```
<?xml versio`enter code here`n="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the second screen" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think it has something to do with the secondpage's xml file, but I'm not too sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create singleton variable save the colour on that. and you will be able to access that variable from all activity. add that colour on Oncreate method. :)

Comment: You may write the values to the SharedPreferences and retrieve them in the other activities. This way also ensures, that your background color is maintained after the app is shut down or killed by android.